# Session Lost on IE Facebook App iFrame

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, session, iframe

I have an issue with my Facebook app when the user uses Internet Explorer.
My app is loaded in iFrame as Canvas Page.

Cookies and Session are lost after post back. It doesn't happen of Firefox at all,
and it doesn't happen on IE if I open my app outside of Facebook, meaning, using the direct URL.

My app is Asp.net C# app but it shouldn't really matter.

I think the issue is larger than a Facebook issue... any website loaded in iFrame using cookies/session is prevented by IE from keeping cookies/session, but is there a way by Facebook to overcome this? I must use sessions in my app, not just to save the reauthentication again and again but for other things too.

Please assist me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

most likely you need to implement P3P headers in your app, see the following for more details:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=452

Comment: Yea I already figured that out from other forums. Thank ya'll.