# Facebook PHP sdk doesnt set cookie with iframe linking

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am using PHP sdk for Facebook.

```
require_once 'facebook-sdk/facebook.php';

session_start();

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'app_id',
    'secret' => 'app_secret',
    'cookie' => true,
));

$facebook->getUser();

if($user){
   // do stuff
}else{
   //redirect to app login
}
```

After this piece of code there is link on my page that points to this same page with a query string.

something like `<a href="/index.php?step=2">Continue</a>`

But when I click this link $user is "0". This happens only şn Safari and IE. When I check cookies set by app doesnt exist in these browsers.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you get the user? are you in an FB-iframe? if so, safari will not set the cookie you are needed. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192142/missing-cookies-on-iframe-in-safari-5-1-5 . for ie send the right P3P header.

Comment: this an canvas app in facebook. So yes it is FB iframe.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding why this gets down voted. Please explain why you downvote

Comment: my solution was below.. don't down this question

Answer (score 2):

Since the user id won't change, is it a problem if you send it via GET?

```
<a href="/index.php?step=2&id=<? echo $user ?>">Continue</a>
```

and then at the top of your script and after getting the $user the way you are doing:

```
if($_GET['step'] == 2){
   $user = $_GET['id'];
}
```

If you really need to keep the cookies you can add this at the top of your script, it must be the first line.

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND ONL COM DEM PRE"');
```

Also you might want to check this questions

[Iframe Facebook application and cookies [Internet Explorer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835285/iframe-facebook-application-and-cookies-internet-explorer)

[Session Lost on IE Facebook App iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205332/session-lost-on-ie-facebook-app-iframe)

wich are related to the header solution.

Comment: savior.. facebook's new PHP sdk doesn't have this line.. it use to be in their old __construct.. poor IE users that all didn't get to use me new app.